# String JSON populate in ListView Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a JSON is String how can I populate JSON data in ListView can anyone help me with code snippet ??

```
String json="[{"Id":"30","Name":"Accident And Emergency Care"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Anesthesiology And Pain Management "},{"Id":"3","Name":"Cardiology And Cardiothoracic Surgery"},{"Id":"32","Name":"Clinical Nutrition And Dietetics"},{"Id":"33","Name":"Critical Care"},{"Id":"34","Name":"Day Care"},{"Id":"9","Name":"Dental Surgery"},{"Id":"19","Name":"Dermatology And Cosmetology"},{"Id":"23","Name":"Dialysis"},{"Id":"6","Name":"E.N.T"},{"Id":"10","Name":"Endocrinology"},{"Id":"20","Name":"Eye"},{"Id":"18","Name":"Gastroenterology"},{"Id":"11","Name":"General Surgery"},{"Id":"39","Name":"Maxillo Facial"},{"Id":"12","Name":"Medicine"},{"Id":"13","Name":"Nephrology"},{"Id":"26","Name":"Neurology"},{"Id":"14","Name":"Neurosurgery"},{"Id":"15","Name":"Obstetrics and Gynaecology"},{"Id":"29","Name":"Oncology"},{"Id":"7","Name":"Orthopedics"},{"Id":"36","Name":"Pathology And Blood Bank"},{"Id":"16","Name":"Pediatrics And Neonatology"},{"Id":"37","Name":"Plastic And Reconstructive Surgery"},{"Id":"17","Name":"Psychiatry"},{"Id":"25","Name":"Pulmonology"},{"Id":"38","Name":"Radiology"},{"Id":"24","Name":"Rheumatology"},{"Id":"5","Name":"Urology"}]}";
```

Comment: Parse the json into array using Gson or you can do that manually and add the array to the adapter of ListView.

Comment: Good start - https://www.androidhive.info/?s=json

Comment: Please provide your api link @Syed Minhaj ul Hassan

Comment: @HarshalDeshmukh I'm getting JSON from http://medicarehospital.pk/WebService.asmx?op=Get_Speciality

Comment: @cprakashagr can u please elaborate how to parse into Gson?

Comment: @Syed Minhaj ul Hassan Check answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ModelClass {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(jsonString, ModelClass[].class);
```

In app level build.gradle: `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'`